# 18.04 and Nvidia GeForce GTX1050 - ASUS GL 503

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, system-installation, asus

18.04 (all flavours) are not working on  ASUS GL 503 VD-FYI Nvidia GeForce GTX1050. Whether by update (17.04) or new install. I tried `nomodeset` option but got a black screen in response!

Comment: When you say not working, how far do you get?  **1)** Are you able to boot the install disk and start the install?  **2)** Does the install go all the way to the reboot, then fail?  **3)** When you get the black screen are you able to use `Ctrl+Alt+F3` to get to a console and log in so that you can do the repair work there?

Comment: Hi, yes i can start (try without install) with usb flashdisk. Process stop with paperwall background and nothing else. No mouse or keybord. Fisrt i had made and update from 17.10 to 18.04 and same issue. I try with "nomodeset" option at boot flashdisk too... and i've the black screen here. i have not try ctrl + alt + f3

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/785762/186740 this was the simplest way around the whole issue without adding ppa sources

Answer (score 3):

I have an Asus GL503VD, I7/1050, i believe the internals are quite the same.

**Install**

1. On grub menu press `e` to edit boot config.
2. Add `acpi_osi=!` after `quiet splash`.
3. Press ctrl+x to boot.

Thats whats needed to boot. Maybe during install you also need nomodeset, i'm not sure.

After install edit the file `/etc/default/grub/` and modify the CMLD_LINUX_DEFAULT line to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!"`

All works fine. Except touchpad and keyboard special keys. I'm still looking for a solution for these.

---

**Update 30/05/2018**

Working on ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.17-rc6, nvidia 396.

---

Fixed on latest kernel `4.17.0-rc6` using nvidia 396 (installed from ubuntu graphics ppa).

No more black screen of death, works Touchpad (except for the ([five finger tap freeze](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1543769)), brightness (but not keys) and everything else.

I believe in a long term the solution will be merged on kernel.

---

**NVIDIA Driver Install**

Boot with `acpi_osi=!`, add ubuntu graphics ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update`

Install nvidia latest graphics (current on post 396.X).

---

**Kernel install**

Go to: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and look for latest kernel. Current on answer [4.17rc6](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17-rc6/)

Download for amd64: `linux-headers`, `linux-headers-XXXXX-generic`, `linux-image-XXXXX-generic`, `linux-modules-XXXX-generic`.

Leave all inside a folder. Open in bash and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Boot with default boot parameters. `acpi_osi=!` is not needed anymore.

Comment: I though this post was dead. I've find the solution and posted on this. Now i updated this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442007/working-acpi-kernel-options-for-asus-fx503vd/445031#445031